# How to anonymously log in to a folder in proftpd

Tags: login, ftp, proftpd

I'm using Ubuntu 17.04 and installed `proftpd`. My default anonymous directory is going to `/home/ftp`.
This is a preview of the FTP folder:

[image]

Is it possible for an anonymous user to login when they have access to 'Download' or 'Upload' folder?

Comment: Why not just disable the anonymous login and force login to access data?  That sounds to me like what your ultimate goal is.

Comment: i did. but soon the ftp server will be access with many users as anonymous. but they don't have permission to access the spesific folder. if they want to access the folder, they have to login with users that i have created.